# I have to create serializer instance without data since i am not accepting any data from user

Tags: django-rest-framework

Here i am trying to create serializer instance without data argument because all i want to create a "Like" object which requires "user" object which i can get from request and "post" object that i am getting through querying Post model with pk but since i am not passing any data argument while deserializing it will throw an error.
So how can create instance without passing data argument or do i have to change my code and add data argument?

```
class Like(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="likes")
    liked_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.RESTRICT, related_name = "liked_posts")

    def __str__(self):
        return "{0} liked by {1}".format(self.post.img, self.liked_by.username)
```

```
class LikeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    liked_by = UserSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Like
        fields = ("id","post", "liked_by")
```

```
class AddLike(APIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def post(self, request, pk):
        post = Post.objects.get(pk=pk)
        user = request.user
        serializer = LikeSerializer()
        if not serializer.is_valid():
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        serializer.save(post=post, liked_by=user)
        return Response(data= serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can set the `post` field as `read_only` in the `LikeSerializer`.

```
class LikeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    liked_by = UserSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Like
        fields = ("id","post", "liked_by")
        extra_kwargs = {
            'post': { 'read_only': True }
        }
```